# Parse Raw HTTP in Python

Tags: python, http, parsing

I am looking for a library or function call in python or an associated library that would let me feed in a raw stream of text data representing an HTTP req/res and that would spit out that information is some sort of meaningful form like a dictionary or list. I do not want to use some built in class or create a bunch of new objects, in my program I am receiving in some raw data and that is just what I've got to work with. Is there already a solution out there for this, or do I have to write an HTTP parser myself?

Edit: Let me clarify what exactly I'm looking to do. I'm looking for something that would take a string like:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 \r\n
Host:www.stackoverflow.com \r\n
User-Agent:Firefox \r\n
etc.
```

And send me back something encapsulating the method, HTTP version, headers and all the rest.

Comment: — here are two questions that I think might address this issue (which I have tried to address in detail there):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115410/does-python-have-a-module-for-parsing-http-requests-and-responses/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html I believe this is the library you are looking for. A little change in name for python 3 but otherwise good to go.

Comment: I looked at that but could not quite find what I needed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that lib revolve around actually making/receiving requests? I don't want to make/receive any requests, I just want to look at raw data. Could you give an example of the method you believe would do this?

Comment: Well the http request, when you recieve it contains the raw header data, and you use this library to create a header dictionary. This is what your post describes. If you are looking to recieve raw text data over a socket you might try http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html but you will be recreating a lot of wheel parts. Conversely if you are receiving the raw text and want a way to parse it into a valid request header you can try http://deron.meranda.us/python/httpheader/pydoc#-parse_token_or_quoted_string but I have not tried this myself.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pure python HTTP parser that is shipped as a fallback implementation for the C/Cython optimized implementation of the [http-parser](https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser) project.

Here is the pure python version:

- https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser/pyparser.py

Here the source of the C version and Cython wrapper:

- https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser/http_parser.c
- https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser/parser.pyx

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at WebOb.  I think the cgi module in the standard library also has an HTTP parser.

Comment: Sweet, webob.Request.accept handles this perfectly: http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#accept-headers

Comment: @Wahnfrieden — I am confused, though, about how to get a raw HTTP request inside of a string, like is shown in the question, and turn it into a WebOb object. I do not see anything in your link that suggests that it is possible. Could you share how you turn HTTP request strings into WebOb objects? (Because I need to on one of my projects!)  :)

Comment: @Brandon sorry I commented prematurely - WebOb parses the part of the header that I needed (just the value of the Accept header), but I don't know about the rest of it.