# Python regular expression for HTTP Request header

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a question about Python regex. I don't have much information about Python regex. I am working with HTTP request messages and parsing them with regex. As you know, the HTTP GET messages are in this format.

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: 10.2.0.12
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I want to parse the URI, method, user-agent, and the host areas of the message. My regex for this job is:

```
r'^({0})\s+(\S+)\s+[^\n]*$\n.*^User-Agent:\s*(\S+)[^\n]*$\n.*^Host:\s*(\S+)[^\n]*$\n'.format('|'.join(methods)), re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

But, when the message comes up with like

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 10.2.0.12
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I can not catch them because of the places of host or, user-agent changed. So I need a generic regex that will catch all of them, even if the places of host, method, uri are changed in the message.

Comment: [This should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers)

Comment: @tuxuday +1 Searching the freakin' web is the most powerful skill in a developer's toolbox.

Comment: I like the method that @tuxuday says. like this m=re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?): (?P<value>.*?)\r\n", req).but in this method I cannot parse "GET" and http version. Is it better to add them at the beginning?

Comment: Do the job the right way. Use `cgi.parse_header()` to get values from the string, or use some tools like WebOb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the whole headers into a dictionary like so?

```
headers = """GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 10.2.0.12
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive"""


headers = headers.splitlines()
firstLine = headers.pop(0)
(verb, url, version) = firstLine.split()
d = {'verb' : verb, 'url' : url, 'version' : version}
for h in headers:
    h = h.split(': ')
    if len(h) < 2:
        continue
    field=h[0]
    value= h[1]
    d[field] = value

print d

print d['User-Agent']
print d['url']
```

Comment: Remember to strip your values and ignore lines that don't contain `:` - `d=dict([[i.strip() for i in l.split(':')] for l in s1.splitlines() if ":" in l])`

Comment: And +1 - liked your approach. As I wrote, Readability counts.

Comment: I need to parse the "GET method" also. without ':'

Comment: Updated to include the first line :)

Answer (score 4):

> Readability Counts [(The Zen of Python)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Use `findall()` for each subexpression you want to find. This way your regex will be short, readable, and independent of the location of the subexpression.

Define a simple, readable regex:

```
>>> user=re.compile("User-Agent: (.*?)\n")
```

Test it with two different http headers:

```
>>> s1='''GET / HTTP/1.0
    Host: 10.2.0.12
    User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
    Accept: */*
    Connection: Keep-Alive'''
>>> s2='''GET / HTTP/1.0
    User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
    Accept: */*
    Host: 10.2.0.12
    Connection: Keep-Alive'''
>>> user.findall(s1)
['Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)']
>>> user.findall(s2)
['Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)']
```

Comment: HTTP spec requires /r/n, so I'd suggest to use re.compile("User-Agent: (.*?)\r\n") instead