# Python http get parameters

Tags: python, http, parameters, get

I build a simple server:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1',8282))
s.listen(1)
client, info = s.accept()

request = ""
i = 0

while True:
    c = client.recv(1)
    request += c
    if c in ["\r","\n"]:
        i += 1
    else:
        i = 0
    if i == 4:
        break

print "============="
print "Client Request"
print "============="
print request

raw_input('Press Enter to send response')

data = """<html>
<body>
<h1>My Amazing Website !!!</h1>
<br>
<font color='yellow' size='20'>Hello (Name)</font>
</body>
</html>
"""

response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
response += "Content-Length: %d\r\n"%len(data)
response += "Connection: Close\r\n"
response += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
response += data

client.send(response)
time.sleep(2)
client.close()
```

Now I can't understand how to replace the "(Name)" in my html code with the get from the url. Lets say my url is: 127.0.0.1:8282/?name=Someone.
How can i get the name who can be found here "GET  /***** HTTP/1.1?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python provides `urlparse` module which contains utilities to get information from urls!

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(urlparse('/test?testing=test&greeting=smile').query)
{'testing': ['test'], 'greeting': ['smile']}
```

I think the tricky part here is to get the `GET` [request path from the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers)

python provides higher level ways to construct webservers. https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer, as well as a number of excellent full stack web frameworks

Comment: Thanks,
can you give me a simple way to get the 'get'?