# Python - Parsing Raw HTTP headers using library, but retaining field ordering

Tags: python, http-headers

I am inquiring about Brandon Rhodes' solution to the problem "Parse raw HTTP headers" in the question [Parse raw HTTP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers). This has brought another question of mine. Is there anyway to use his solution, but maintain the ordering of the HTTP fields?

In his solution, fields are keys in a dictionary. However, the loss of information inherent in this model is the order of the HTTP fields, which I require.

Comment: If you want to get a reliable order you should not use dict, use a list solution instead.

Comment: I would just get the first word of each line of the header (space delimited for the request line, and colon delimited for the rest), but I think RFC allows fields to span multiple lines.