# Why does this regex not match in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the regular expression

```
(GET|POST) (/api/\w+) (HTTP/1\.\d)(?:.*\\r\\n\\r\\n)(\S+)?
```

which I'm trying to match against HTTP GET and HTTP POST requests. I'm using the helpful [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) website to format my regular expression, and according to it, the regular expression should match both the formats I'm seeking.

[Here's my regular expression on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ghlo0L/3).

However, when I input into Python itself and call `re.split()`, (on an input of strings), it doesn't split the POST request. It only splits the GET request. I thought it had something to do with the way regex101 parses `\r\n` (CRLF) versus how Python does it, so I double-checked and made sure that in Python, I actually type in `\r\n\` inside the regex, and not `\\r\\n`, as I did in regex101. Yet it still doesn't work.

How can I get the regular expression to work inside Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your'e just missing an additional `\r\n` after `HTTP/1.0`. This will work:

```
'POST /api/gettime HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\n\r\n100000+200000'
```

Comment: OK, I see that now. Good catch. But I actually do need to have the POST format have only one ```\r\n``` after ```HTTP/1.0```. So is there a way I can use one regex to handle both ```\r\n\``` and ```\r\n\r\n```? I'm fiddling around with the regular expression right now, but am not having much luck.

Comment: @WaterGuy `(\r\n)+` will match one or more `\r\n` or `(\r\n){1,2}` to only match 1 or 2 occurrences

Comment: @Nick I gave that a shot, and yet it didn't work. I tried ```(?:\\r\\n)+``` and yet it only matched one \r\n.

Comment: @WaterGuy It's working for me on your regex101 page: https://regex101.com/r/Ghlo0L/4

Comment: Do you need to preserve the `\r`s and `\n`s? If not, you could pre-process the string to replace them with say, a space. I suspect you're re-inventing the wheel here. Have you considered using an existing http parsing library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers

Comment: @MCI Unfortunately, usage of any HTTP parsing library is disallowed. Yes, I do need to preserve the ```\r```s and ```\n```s.

Comment: @Nick Hmm, it does seem to be working now. That's strange, it wasn't working before. Maybe I made a typo somewhere.

Comment: @WaterGuy chalk it up to the ghost in the machine. Glad to hear it's working.