# How to replay HTTP requests in Python

Tags: python, http, replay

I would like to replay an arbitrary raw HTTP request in python.
As an example, lets use an arbitrary GET request from my chromium browser to Google:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.de
Cookie: CONSENT=PENDING+071; AEC=ARSKqsKvfEvPS9Vp1bDM6YMPdHpVOoH357W-7q3cqtdDwYeHf3MqPEO1xA; SOCS=CAISHAgBEhJnd3NfMjAyMzAyMjMtMF9SQzEaAmRlIAEaBgiAn-WfBg; NID=511=N6YvXcWd_hnVVnV8w6JK4jscqE2pEt8MuTrw3yZJp-84ZxV6RJLee_yj2DEo2UJuOse0sqLjdnAD7qgPw9al7aEJqsQOCAQPIs21rLy5HQ5IAoObj7icI7ayKJttejI9Va2jDFkk0ZLvUC7P_VPJuxRJyhvLspqU1YVUcYCThrYizbo; 1P_JAR=2023-2-25-20
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Chromium";v="110"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.5481.78 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
X-Client-Data: CO3/ygE=
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
```

Since I want my request to look exactly like the above, an obvious way would be to use the socket library:

```
def send(host, port, message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall(message)
        print("%s" % message.decode('us-ascii'))
        data = s.recv(1024)

    print("%s" % data)
```

However, that way, I obviously can't use TLS or proxies (without writing my own libraries).

So, I thought the request library could be worth a try since it already supports TLS and proxies out of the box. But I can't figure out how to load my HTTP request that I want to replay.
I suppose the library was not designed for that.

I could try something like this (from the docs):

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()

req = Request('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers)
prepped = req.prepare()

# do something with prepped.body
prepped.body = 'No, I want exactly this as the body.'

# do something with prepped.headers
del prepped.headers['Content-Type']

resp = s.send(prepped,
    stream=stream,
    verify=verify,
    proxies=proxies,
    cert=cert,
    timeout=timeout
)

print(resp.status_code)
```

but I still would have to first parse the headers of my request manually.
If there a library that takes care of that?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: You can parse headers in this format using the `email` module from the standard library, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! The `email` library works fine to extract the headers. But I'll still go with the `aioreq` solution, because like that I can simply send raw HTTP requests over TLS without fiddling them into the `request` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLS can be used with sockets**; you just need to wrap it in `ssl` library sockets.

However, there are **many** libraries that can do it, so you don't have to use TLS yourself.

You can use the [aioreq](https://github.com/karosis88/aioreq) library, which is a simple asynchronous HTTP client that can be used to send raw HTTP request messages.

`Aioreq` does not support proxies for raw requests, but it does allow you to do many interesting things and see how the HTTP protocol works.

This is your request (without the `Cookie` header, it was quite large:D).

```py
import asyncio
import aioreq
import socket

async def main():
    hostname = "google.de"
    transport = aioreq.Transport()
    await transport.make_connection(
        ip=socket.gethostbyname(hostname),
        port=443,
        ssl=True,  # True if you want to use SSL/TLS
        server_hostname=hostname
    )

    raw_request_bytes = ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Host: google.de\r\n"
'Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Chromium";v="110"\r\n'
"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0\r\n"
'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"\r\n'
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n"
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                         "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.5481.78 Safari/537.36\r\n"
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,'
                         'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7\r\n'
"X-Client-Data: CO3/ygE=\r\n"
"Sec-Fetch-Site: none\r\n"
"Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\n"
"Sec-Fetch-User: ?1\r\n"
"Sec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\n"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
).encode("ascii")

    status_line, headers_line, content = await transport.send_http_request(
        raw_request_bytes
    )
    resp = aioreq.parsers.ResponseParser.parse(status_line, headers_line, content)
    print(resp)
asyncio.run(main())
```

As a result, we have the variable `resp`, which is our HTTP Response with all of its required attributes, such as (.headers, .content, .status, ...)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly! (Except for HTTP proxies of course, but I can do without proxy support for now).