# How to extract HTTP message body in BaseHTTPRequestHandler.do_POST()?

Tags: python, http, post, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

In the `do_POST()` method of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` I can access the headers of the POST request simply via the property `self.headers`. But I can't find a similar property for accessing the body of the message. How do I then go about doing that?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can access POST body in `do_POST` method like this:

for **python 2**

```
content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
```

for **python 3**

```
content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
```

and then read the data

```
post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
```

Comment: any way to get them external from the do_POST() method?

Comment: @KevinDTimm what is the reason to do this?

Comment: Note that this leads to a `TypeError` if the content-length header is not set (e.g. by calling `curl -X POST http://your-endpoint`). So either make sure to catch it or set a default value for the content-length header: `content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))`

Comment: in python3: `self.headers.get(...)`

Comment: Any reason why `self.rfile.read()` doesn't just read the entire input on its own? Why do we need to specify the number of bytes to read?

Comment: @sevko because otherwise you will start reading the next pipelined request sent by the client.

Comment: This doesn't feel safe. What happens if a malicious client sends a very large `'Content-Length'` value? Won't that cause the server to read more data than it should?