# BaseHTTPRequestHandler parse_request() never returns

Tags: python, httprequest, sublime-text-plugin

I'm totally new to Python and trying to create a sublime plugin that needs a WebSocket server. I found [this](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) and tried to port it to Python 3 (originally written in 2?) and run into a problem with the following code:

```
class HTTPRequest(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def __init__(self, request_text):
      self.rfile = StringIO(request_text)
      self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
      self.error_code = self.error_message = None
      print('before')
      self.parse_request()
      print('after') # never reached!
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server/blob/master/SimpleWebSocketServer/SimpleWebSocketServer.py#L26).

The `parse_reqeust()` method never returns. The `'after'` is never printed. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to debug things like this in Python?

(The technique above seems to come from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5964334/416797))